# CardView background alpha colour not working correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, android-shape

i am trying to make `CardView` with elevation but the issue is when i use no-alpha color like `"#ffffff"` it works fine but when i set some alpha color like `#b0ffffff`it shows another inner view with elevation
like this

[image]

but when i set non-alpha color like`"#ffffff"` it works fine

[image]

and this is my layout

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#b0ffffff"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#b0ffffff"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/people" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

btw i am trying to make a view like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just remove the line:

```
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#b0ffffff"
```

and it should work

Comment: but i want to assign alpha color by default its showing white color

Comment: in card view background do nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
           <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#B0FFFFFF"
                app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/people" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: its giving me same inner rounded view which i have mentioned above